# Parsing JSON using org.json in Java for large JSON file/Watson Personality

Tags: java, json, parsing, watson, org.json

I did some looking but didn't quite understand how I was supposed to pull specific values from this string of json: http://pastebin.com/mvMrcii5

I generated it using the watson personality insights api and from my understanding I should just be able to use `org.json` to convert the profile object used to retrieve the json into an actual `JSONObject` and so far I've been able to type

```
JSONObject objectArray = new JSONObject(profile);
```

and it hasn't thrown any errors.  I just don't know how I would get a specific `trait_id` and its related percentile from within the JSON with hundreds of different instances of the same references.  Ideally, they'd all be placed in different variables in order to print them separately.  I could also parse it as a CSV if selecting specific objects within the JSON is too much trouble.

I'd be really appreciative of any help, banging my head against a wall with this one.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please review our [SO Question Checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Comment: Your question is much too vague. All we can answer is that the way to extract information out of a JSONObject is described in the API documentation of JSONObject. Have you read it? Have you tried anything?

Comment: I tried anything to do with org.json and gson but it just was too confusing and in the end far too complex.  I posted my working code below and use jsonpath as my library of choice in the end!

Answer (score 0):

In the end I worked out how to do it.  For anyone using the Watson SDK and Java wanting a solution, here's mine:

```
    Profile profile = service.getProfile(secondArray).execute();
    String textProfile = profile.toString();        
    Object document = Configuration.defaultConfiguration().jsonProvider().parse(textProfile);
    String nameWatson = JsonPath.read(document, "$.personality[0].name");
    Double percentWatson = JsonPath.read(document, "$.personality[0].percentile");
```

This works by using the JayWay JSONPath library, add to maven with:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

First line of Java executes the Watson query and stores it in a profile object as profile in the default JSON format.  Next converts it to a string and stores it as textProfile.  Next line uses the jsonpath library to store the now converted profile as something the jsonpath library can read via the textProfile variable.  Second to last line then traverses the hierarchy of the Watson JSON layout to store the first instance of name under the personality section as nameWatson and the same idea applies to the next line.  If you have trouble with this, print the profile variable to screen and save it to a text file to reference to it later and use [this](https://jsonpath.herokuapp.com/?path=$..author) to test it before implementing it into your code.  Note that using any modifiers such as ".." will throw an error unless put into a list so make sure to use definite references (read more on the jsonpath github)